# Why will my if block not execute when it meets the condition?

Tags: python

Can someone please explain to me why my solution will not work in Leet Code. It seems like the code does not pick up on the compliment being in the dictionary (if statement), even though 2 is in the dictionary. I don't understand why. Thank you in advance!

'''

```
      def two_sum(nums, target):
        for i in range(0, len(nums) -1):
           compl = target - nums[i]
        
           if compl in dict: return [dict[compl], i]
           else: dict[nums[i]] = i
```

'''

Comment: how is `dict` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If `dict` is defined as the name of the dictionary, then check if 2 is a string-type or a int-type within the dictionary because your if-statement only works if the dictionary key is an integer.

The line `if compl in dict:` is asking if `compl` is in the `dict` type object. You need to access the dictionary by its name, not by using the term `dict`.

[Here is a link that shows how to access a dictionary in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries_access.asp). Notice how in the first example, they use the name of the dictionary `thisdict` to access the dictionary. In your case, you would write

```
def two_sum(nums, target):
    for i in range(0, len(nums) -1):
        compl = target - nums[i]
        
        if compl in dict_name: return [dict_name[compl], i]
        else: dict_name[nums[i]] = I
```

and substitute `dict_name` with the name of the dictionary.

Comment: `dict` also can be used as a name for an instance of a dictionary, arguably a very bad practice but still